# Creating AWS Audit Manager Assessment that targets a specific EC2 Instance using the ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know that AWS Audit Manager can target EC2 instances in an aws account, but we wish to target specific applications on running on specific ec2 instance. I have tried using custom controls, custom frameworks but still can get the right configuration.

I need pointers as to what I am missing in setting up the assessments etc